# use grunt to restart a phantomjs process

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm using grunt to have some tasks done every time I change my code ( jshint  for example ) and I want to reload a phantomJs process every time I have changes.

The first way I found is to use grunt.util.spawn to run phantomJs the first time.

```
//  http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.spawn
var phantomJS_child = grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd: './phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs',
    args: ['./phantomWorker.js']
},
function(){
    console.log('phantomjs done!'); // we never get here...
});
```

And then, every time watch restarts, another task uses grunt.util.spawn to kill the phantomJs process, which is of course VERY ugly.

Is there any better way to  do it?
The thing is that the phantomJs process is not teminating because I use it as a webserver to server a REST API with JSON.

Can I have a grunt callback or something whenever watch kicks in so I can close my previous phantomJs process before I re-run the task to create a new one?

I used grunt.event to make a handler, but I cannot see how to access the phantomjs process in order to kill it.

```
grunt.registerTask('onWatchEvent',function(){

    //  whenever watch starts, do this...
    grunt.event.on('watch',function(event, file, task){
        grunt.log.writeln('\n' + event + ' ' + file + ' | running-> ' + task); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This *entirely untested* code could be a solution for your problem.

Node's native child spawning function `exec` immediately returns a reference to the child process, which we can keep around to later kill it. To use it we can create a custom grunt task on the fly, like so:

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK. phantomjs is undefined every time the watcher re-executes the task
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    phantomjs;

grunt.registerTask('spawn-phantomjs', function() {

    // if there's already phantomjs instance tell it to quit
    phantomjs && phantomjs.kill();

    // (re-)start phantomjs
    phantomjs = exec('./phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs ./phantomWorker.js',
        function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            grunt.log.write(stdout);
            grunt.log.error(stderr);
            if (err !== null) {
                grunt.log.error('exec error: ' + err);
            }
    });

    // when grunt exits, make sure phantomjs quits too
    process.on('exit', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('killing child...');
        phantomjs.kill();
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm just playing with grunt to get familiar with it before I use it. With this way we are manually killing the process again. I didn't know that we can use the 'exit' event like this. Are you sure that whenever watch is reloading the tasks, this 'exit' event will trigger? Killing it on 'exit' is the best case of course.

Comment: Sorry, I confused your use case with stuff I read on another tab. Just made some edits to the code snippet, with what I thought would match your use case. It doesn't work however. Gruntfile.js is executed anew every time the watcher detects a change. Thus no persisted reference to phantomjs is possible. Not like this anyway.